# Npm run command in child directory

Tags: javascript, npm

I have the following directory structure:

```
- a
  -node_modules
  -package.json
  -b
   -package.json
```

In the `a` directory, I'm running `npm i del`. When I add to the `package.json` of `b` the following script:

```
{
  "name": "b",
  "scripts": {
    "del": "del file.txt"
  }
}
```

I'm getting an error:

> sh: del: command not found

How can I use the parent bin inside the child? (I don't want to install anything in the child directory)

Comment: Sorry, have to ask a basic question: Windows or Mac? `del` is a Windows command, yes?

Answer (score 3):

You can move to your parent with cd command and then execute the script.

```
{
 "name": "b",
 "scripts": {
   "del": "cd .. && del file.txt" // or "cd .. && npm run del" if del script is in parent's package.json
 }
}
```

Comment: But then I need to change the path, no? del b/file.txt

Comment: since `cd ..` will move you to parent directory. so path should be relative to parent directory.

Comment: Seems verbose to me, there is no cleaner way?

Comment: ideally one should not execute package.json scripts from child to parent. your can change your approach and only use parent's package.json scripts. when your application grows this might create another headache, if you do this from multiple child folder.